# Digital Signature and the identical passwords

Tags: c#, digital-signature

If Two users enter the same password, The values in the DB will be the same.

Any advice , please

```
#region "Digital Signature"
public static String EncryptDS (this String dataToEncrypt)
{
  //Convert dataToEncrypt to byte array
  byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(dataToEncrypt);
  //===================================
  //Create Crypto Service provides params (24 allows SHA256 hashing alogrithm)
  CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
  cspParams = new CspParameters(24);
  cspParams.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
  cspParams.KeyContainerName = "TT_KEY";
  //====================================
  //Generate asymmetric key
  RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
  //=====================================
  //hash and then encrypt the hash(digitally sign)
  byte[] sig = rsa.SignData(plainTextBytes, "SHA256");
  //=====================================
  //Return signed encrypt the hash (digitally sign)
  return Convert.ToBase64String(sig);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practise for password hashing includes creating a reasonably long salt (random sequence of characters) which is stored in the database beside the password.

When hashing the password, concatenate it with the salt first. If two users have the same password, they will have different salts so the hashes will be different. This also helps prevent rainbow tables/mass brute forcing.

Comment: So, I will use Hash Salting with Digital Signature to avoid the identical passwords. Thank you for your help and your support.